# Parallel Execution of all tables in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a SQL script to rebuild and reorganize indexes that runs using the Execute SQL task in SSIS. The SQL script verifies for fragmentation and rebuilds or reorganize based on that on tables in sequential manner. This process is taking a lot of time. Sometimes, if a table has 2 indexes that has to be rebuild, the other tables have to wait on the 1st table with 2 indexes to be finished and then start executing.

Now I want that all these tables that have 1 index to run simultaneously in such a way that first table will start execution, at the same time second will start and so on without waiting on tables with multiple indexes to complete.

For example the below query gives me the row number, table name and index names of tables

```
SELECT (ROW_NUMBER ()OVER(Partition By TableNAME  ORDER BY TableName)) AS RowNumber,TableName, IndexName
FROM (
    select DISTINCT object_name(i.object_id) AS TableName,i.name AS IndexName
    FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(DB_NAME()), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) ips
    JOIN sys.objects o ON ips.object_id = o.object_id
    JOIN sys.schemas sc ON o.schema_id = sc.schema_id
    JOIN sys.indexes i ON ips.object_id = i.object_id AND ips.index_id = i.index_id
    where ips.avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 5
) T
```

Now using this I separated the tables having 1 index and having more than 1 index.

I am  not able to understand, How to run all the tables with 1 index in parallel, that is all the tables with single index should start executing the SQL script at the same time. I want to do it in SSIS using a container, but I am stuck.

Can somebody come up with a solution?

Comment: Given a result set of `(1, tblA, PK_tblA), (1, tblB, PK_tblB), (2, tblB, AK_tblB)` the desired result is that tblA PK is rebuild simultaneously with tblB. When tblB is complete, then the second index for tblB begins rebuilding - do I have that correct?

Comment: Yes that is absolutely correct. It should work the same way you mentioned

Comment: What if you have 100 tables, some with more than 1 index - do you really want to try and rebuild all of them at the same time or is there a reasonable limit of concurrency, say 5? My concern is you'll saturate your IO trying to rebuild all a the same time and then you'll be a worse state

Comment: I can do it with a concurrency 5 but these 5 should run at the same time.

Comment: I am suggesting a different approach, you can try it or not upto you. I have generally used the rule of "IF fragmentation <5% do nothing, 5%-30% only reorganize, more than 30% rebuild"; These percentages are not set in stone so you may have to go with something which works for you. As @bilinkc stated, the more tables you have the worse your IO gets. I believe you can work with reorganizing some ad rebuilding some (Rerganize is faster than Rebuid). You can read more [here](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/sqlskills-sql101-rebuild-vs-reorganize/)